# Access elements thats being hovered over thats not bags? Dragula and Angular 2

Tags: angular, drag, dragula

I've got 2 dragula bags, i want to drag elements from 1 bag to the other and the elements in the second bag should not be effected or moved i simply want to know which element is being hovered over in the second bag. And not the bag name.

Is this possible? Im using Ng2-Dragula.

Im currently using the built in functions, but there are no parameters for elements thats being hovered over except the bag.

```
this.dragulaService.over.subscribe((value:any) => {
     this.onOver(value);
});

private onOver(args:any) 
{
    let [bag, element, target, source, smth] = args;
}
```